# Invalid statement in fillWindow()

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Am I missing a `close()`?

Ok, I have an error on my emulator, but it doesn't force close. It's a cursor `Invalid Starement in fillWindow()` with a PID of 651. I know it has to do wih my database cursor. My ListView is filled by `startManagingCursor(c)`, but I'm not sure If I need to close it, I'm **not** using a managed query.

In my onCreate I have

```
db = new DBase(this);
db.open();
fillData();
db.close();
```

and in my onResume I have

```
db.open();
fillData();
db.close();
```

I've tried putting `db.close();` in my onDestroy and it still throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCreate

```
db = new DBase(this);
db.open();
fillData();
```

onResume

```
fillData();
```

onDestroy

```
db.close();
```

worked.